# Java Objects not stored when written

Tags: java, android, object, stream, output

I am currently working on an android project and my objects are not stored when I write them out.

This is my way of writing them, Where cont is an ArrayList of type Contact

```
if (contacts.size() > 0){
        File fout = new File(c.getCacheDir(), "contacts.acl");
        if (fout.exists()){
            try{
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fout, false)));
                for (Contact cont : contacts){
                    Log.d(MYACT, "Writing out: " + cont.getfName());
                    out.writeObject(cont);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

and this is how I read them

```
private ArrayList<Contact> readContacts(){
    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    File file = new File(c.getCacheDir(), "contacts.acl"); //get contact file
    Log.d(MYACT, "Launch File exists: " + file.exists());
    if (file.exists()){ // if it exists then read in contacts while there are contacts left
        try{

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
            Log.d(MYACT, "Reading from file. Available: " + in.available());
            while (in.available() > 0){
                Contact cont = (Contact)in.readObject();
                Log.d(MYACT, "Read in: " + cont.getfName());
                contactList.add(cont);
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else // else creates the file
        try{
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){}

        return contactList;
}
```

At first I though it was because I missed closing a stream, but they are all closed. What could be the problem? Is there any other solution to storing objects. Originally I had it so that it stored each Contact in the same file, but then I transferred it to storing the ArrayList of contacts.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you check that your `if` condition is executing

Comment: the if (fout.exists()) condition is met. The program seems to write the information out, however when I check the available bits in the read it always produces 0 and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You checked the file also on which its writing, the data is there?

Comment: There is information written to the file. I know that the extension shouldn't matter, but do you think it might be interfering?

Comment: I ll be needing the complete code. Can you paste the code here

Comment: I can post the main code. I won't be including other Activities that my first one links to. My Contact class just holds info. My class it too long to post in the comments, and I can't yet post on my own thread. Can I email it to you?

Comment: okay just edit the question and show

Comment: Always close streams in a `finally` block!!

Comment: Why the `file.exists()` test? How are you ever going to get started?

Answer (score 1):

You have written onto `ObjectOutputStream`. So no need to check in.available()
Replace the while loop

```
while (in.available() > 0){
                Contact cont = (Contact)in.readObject();
                Log.d(MYACT, "Read in: " + cont.getfName());
                contactList.add(cont);
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to

```
while (true){
                        Contact cont = (Contact)in.readObject();
                        contactList.add(cont);
                    }
                }
                catch(EOFException eof){}
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: @sirlink99 in case your problem is solved. forget not to tick my answer..:)